# Is it possible to mutate only within selected groups?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I wonder whether it is possible with `mutate` to apply a function to only selected **groups** (not observations!)?

I have multiple variables indicating whether an object was exposed to a specific kind treatment in a given time point.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2), treatment = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0))
```

I aim to make a variable with relative time to treatment in the following manner:

```
df  %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(relative_time = seq_along(treatment) - which(treatment %in% 1))

     id treatment relative_time
  <dbl>     <dbl>         <int>
1     1         0            -2
2     1         0            -1
3     1         1             0
4     1         0             1
5     2         0            -1
6     2         1             0
7     2         0             1
```

However, the question is how to handle groups that were not treated?

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2), treatment = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0))
```

I've tried to apply `ifelse()` to exclude the groups with all zeroes. It indeed excludes non-treated groups, but the result for treated groups is wrong then. It seems that all the elements of the group are assigned with the first element of `seq_along(...) - which(...)`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(relative_time = ifelse(sum(treatment) > 0, seq_along(treatment) - which(treatment %in% 1), NA))

     id treatment relative_time
  <dbl>     <dbl>         <int>
1     1         0            -2
2     1         0            -2
3     1         1            -2
4     1         0            -2
5     2         0            NA
6     2         0            NA
7     2         0            NA
```

Since I have many of such treatment, I would like to avoid filtering and creating multiple dataframes for each treatment type and rather use `mutate_at()`.

I would be grateful for your kind advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `sum(treatment) > 0` is of length 1, `ifelse()` only returns the first number and recycle it to the length of current group. In this case, `if() ... else ...` is suitable.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(relative_time = if(sum(treatment) > 0) seq_along(treatment) - which(treatment == 1) else NA)

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# # Groups:   id [2]
#      id treatment relative_time
#   <dbl>     <dbl>         <int>
# 1     1         0            -2
# 2     1         0            -1
# 3     1         1             0
# 4     1         0             1
# 5     2         0            NA
# 6     2         0            NA
# 7     2         0            NA
```

Comment: Dear Darren, thank you for your answer! However, in my case it somehow does not work: for non-treated group the result is just the output of `seq_along`...

Comment: @Asikaz could you give me an example?

Comment: Perhaps `group_by(id, treatment)`?

Comment: Seems that the problem is in R version or something: it works perfectly on my laptop, but didn't work on my office computer. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

We could do this with `match`.  After grouping by 'id', subtract the `row_number` with the row index where value is 1 in 'treatment'.  By default, if there is no `match`, it returns `NA` and any arithmetic operations with `NA` results in `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(relative_time = row_number() - match(1, treatment))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
#     id treatment relative_time
#  <dbl>     <dbl>         <int>
#1     1         0            -2
#2     1         0            -1
#3     1         1             0
#4     1         0             1
#5     2         0            NA
#6     2         0            NA
#7     2         0            NA
```

Comment: Dear akrun, thank you for this short and very handy solution!